# Solving product of binomial powers in integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

I have to find $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ such that

$$(1 + x)^5(1+ax)^6 = 1 + bx + 10x^2 + \ldots + a^6x^{11}$$

Now, as far as I can tell for all $a$ there is a solution when $b = 5$, so a solution is $a \in \mathbb{Z}^*$, $b=5$. However, the problem asks for a unique solution. How can there be a unique solution? Or maybe I'm misreading the problem?

Comment: Hint: You need to look at the $x$ term, and also the $x^2$ term, of both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$(1+x)^5=1+5x+10x^2+\cdots$$ and $$(1+ax)^6=1+6ax+15a^2x^2+\cdots$$
Multiplying these we get $$(1+x)^5(1+ax)^6=1+(5+6a)x+(10+30a+15a^2)x^2+\cdots$$
Equating coefficients of this polynomial with $1+bx+10x^2+\cdots$ yields the equations $$5+6a=b$$ and $$10+30a+15a^2=10$$
Please let me know if you need assistance in solving these equations for $a,b$.

Comment: Where did you get $30a$?

Comment: $30a=5\times 6a$, when you multiply the two polynomials.  Do you know FOIL?

Comment: Yes, I understand